# Rango de fecha de 6 meses - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

mi consulta es que tengo un query el cual tengo 3 variables declaradas

```
DECLARE @FechaInicio DATE;
DECLARE @FechaFinal DATE 
DECLARE @Tipo INT
```

Las cuales la variable @Tipo= 1 entonces que me traiga toda una base de clientes hasta la @FechaFinal

Por ejemplo asi

```
IF @Tipo=1
BEGIN
 
SELECT DISTINCT
LEFT('01', 2)                                                                                                     AS [TipodeInstitucion] 
,LEFT('34', 2)                                                                                                    AS [CodigodeInstitucion]
,LEFT (FORMAT(@FechaFinal,'yyyyMMdd'),8)                                                                          AS [FechadeReportedeDatos]
,LEFT (pc.ClientId, 20)                                                                                            AS [CIF] 

,UPPER(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE
(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE
(RTRIM(LTRIM(LEFT( 
CONCAT(pc.FirstNameLocal,' ',pc.MNameLocal,' ',pc.LastNameLocal,' ',pc.SecondMNameLocal)
,80))),'MARTIN1EQ1ZE','MARTINEZ'),'O O O 0' ,'SIN NOMBRE'),'?', 'N'),'BE3LASKE','BELASKE'),'0',''),
',',''),'8',''),'3',''),'11196',''),'4',''),'|',''),'/','.'),'<',''),'&','.'),'Ñ','N'),'9',''),'1',''),'¡',''),':',''),'´',''),'"','')
,'¨',''),'- - - -','SIN NOMBRE'),'','SIN NOMBRE'),'`',''),'-',''),'(','.'),')',''))

                                                                                                                   AS [NombredelCliente]

FROM  CWCORE2.CWNET_HON.dbo.Clients AS pc 

WHERE pc.Created <=  @FechaFinal  
END
```

Lo que hace este query es traerme todos los clientes hasta una fecha determinada, ahora si @Tipo=2 quiero que me haga la busqueda entre rango de fecha pero de exactamente 6 meses, por ejemplo si ya saque un reporte utilizando @Tipo=1 al 31 de enero 2021, quiero sacar otro reporte pero del 1 de febrero en 6 meses en adelante, entiendo que EOMONTH solamente saca de un mes, no se si habra alguna funcion para los 6 meses

Comment: Busca DATEADD()

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver tu problema deberás tener en cuenta dos cosas.

1. Periodos de consultas
2. Uso de funciones

Para el periodo de consultas debes tener en cuenta desde que fecha hasta que fecha requieres consultar, para ilustrarte un poco he hecho el siguiente ejercicio con variables

En el cual obtengo la fecha de día, y mediante la función DATEADD, le indico que a esa fecha le descuente el numero de meses que requieres

```
declare @date_day date = getdate();
print @date_day
--te imprimira la fecha del dia

declare @fecha_finaly date
set @fecha_finaly = DATEADD(MONTH,-6,@date_day)
print @fecha_finaly
--te imprimirá la fecha del dia menos 6 meses
```

a partir de aquí, podrías en tu `where` añadir las validaciones, comparando tu campo con el valor contenido en las variables